# php_xsl.dll troubles

Tags: php

Please, can somebody give me link to php_xsl.dll for this php version:

> PHP Version 5.3.1 Build Date Nov 19
>   2009 10:16:45 Compiler MSVC6 (Visual
>   C++ 6.0) Architecture x86

in my AMP was no xsl module, and I cant find in google link to my php version php_xsl.dll

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what AMP package are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the peril of using those all-in-one tools that do all the thinking for you.  Unless you already know how they're going to work, you may end up with problems.

Your best bet is going to be grabbing [an appropriate copy of PHP 5.3.2](http://windows.php.net/download/) and installing it yourself.  5.3.1 no longer seems available for download, probably due to many security fixes in 5.3.2.  5.3.2 seems to contain the XSL extension.

*Don't even think* of taking the XSL extension from 5.3.2 and trying it in your 5.3.1 copy, the results are likely to be crashtastic.

Comment: its is exacly what I don't wan't to do(. But looks like there are no other way.
Thank you for the answer

Comment: Don't worry, you'll come out of it knowing more than when you dove in.  Knowledge is power, after all!  ;)